# How to set the page 'to.meta' attribute in the RouteMiddleware

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have the following routeMiddleware:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  console.log(to);
  useHead({
    title: `MYApp - ${(String(to.meta.name))}`,
  })
}
```

How can I change the title page-per-page? For example: I have an index page and a product page. I would like the to.name on my index page to be called 'MYApp - Home'.
And the to.name on my product page to be called 'MYApp - Shop'.

I have tried adding the following to my index page, but to.meta remains empty:

```
useHead({
  meta: [
    { name: 'Home', content: 'Content' }
  ],
})
```

How can I do this?

SOLUTION: found it. It's not useHead(), it's definePageMeta().

Comment: You likely ask about wrong thing. `name` is commonly route id, it's not intended to be human readable. If you want it to be that way, use some kind of metadata for the routes. Check https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo

Comment: @EstusFlask You are correct. I have edited with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `useHead()`, I need to use `definePageMeta()`.

With this code I can access it in my middleware.

```
definePageMeta({
  title: 'Home',
});
```